# Exclude *.a file when building the app for simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12, xcode12.5

Currently, I have an issue with one of the libs that I use in the project, it simply won't let me make the build for the iOS simulator.

Getting the following error message:
*Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked library '!@#$%^&.a' was built for iOS.*

In my class I have the following code:

```
#if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR==0)
void !@#$%^&_init(void);
#endif
```

I have tried to exclude the file when building the app for the iPhone simulator by adding it in *Build Settings > Build Options > Excluded Source File Names > Any iOS Simulator SDK*

I have also tried to exclude the following architectures: arm64, arm64e, and armv7.

Setting Build Active Architecture Only to YES, didn't do the trick for me, nor validating build product nor validate workspace.

Actually, none of the above-mentioned solutions worked for me, so I had to ask this question here.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you should be able to change Build system to "Legacy Build System" under File/Project Settings.
The proper solution would be to package your library as XCFramework.

Comment: this is also something that didn't work for me either, I've tried it

Comment: Trying "Legacy Build System" or creating XCFramework or both?

Comment: trying legacy build system